# Clicking webelement with html tag paper-icon-button

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to focus and click a button with below DOM.

But when I'm getting `element not found` error.

I tried using JSE, JAVA and Actions class also

```
<paper-icon-button id="print" icon="cr:print" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" title="Print" aria-label="Print">
      </paper-icon-button>
```

Comment: attach code sample, html sample and error

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: add your java code you have tried?